# Runif is not generating a uniform distribution

Tags: r, random, uniform-distribution

```
set.seed(1432)    
n_len <- 400000
jdc<- data.frame(rnd = numeric(n_len))
jdc$rnd <- runif(n_len,0,1)
ggplot(jdc,aes(x = rnd)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

As you will note the distribution of the random variable drops off towards both boundaries.

I am trying to sample based on some i less than rnd, but range of i is between 0, .05, thus this distribution is a problem.

Comment: google "kernel density boundary bias"

Answer (score 12):

This has more to do with the density estimator than with `runif()`. It's better to use a histogram to look at the data:

```
ggplot(jdc, aes(x = rnd)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary = 0)
```

[image]

As [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) has pointed out, one can also create a histogram that shows a similar bias to your density estimator:

```
ggplot(jdc, aes(x = rnd)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

The advantage of the histogram is that it is easy to understand, why this happens. The left- and right-most bins are centered on 0 and 1, respectively. This means that, e.g., the left-most bin goes from -0.005 to 0.005. But there are no data points below zero, so this interval contains only about half as many points as the others.

Comment: Note that the arguments to `geom_histogram` are important here, as one would see similar "anomalies" without them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @joran. You are right, of course. I will add a second plot to show case this, once I have received the permission to make the code in the question reproducible.

Comment: @Stibu I think you should feel free to go ahead and make that edit to the OP. They can always roll back your edit if they don't like it (which I think is exceedingly unlikely).

Comment: And also, all the content here is CC BY-SA. The SA (sharealike) bit takes care of itself here (you are sharing on [so] which has the same license as, well, [so]) and BY (by attribution) is implied via the editing (if you reuse in your answer, I might add "using OP's example" or some such). You need to be more careful if you take content elsewhere, but here, just go for it.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, Josh O'Brien, Thanks for your comments. I thought that edits that go beyond correcting typos and other small stuff should better be done in collaboration with the author. But then again, one can easily argue that my edit is very much in line with the intent of the author and therefore no issue at all. I'll be more audacious next time...